# ant .svn is copied, source includes are ignored

Tags: svn, ant, javac

```
  <target name="compile">
<javac destdir="${build.dir}/classes"
  classpathref="${build.classpath}"
  debug="on">
  <src path="${src.dir}"/>
  <include name="package1/**/*.java"/>
</javac>
```

Issues

1. compile all java files under the source ${src.dir}, not only package1 but also other packages.
2. the source dir is in the SVN checkout workspace, .svn is copied to the ${build.dir}/classes.

Thanks for help.

Comment: i want to compile the package1 only, not all packages. but all packages are got compiled. I looked at .svn, it does not have .java, but contains *.java.svn-base, *.java.svn-work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are telling javac only to compile sources in `package1`.

Remove this line:

`<include name="package1/**/*.java"/>`

The `.svn` directory contains files with `.java` extension. Add this to `javac` task:

`<excludes name="**/.svn/**"/>`

Your target code will be:

```
<target name="compile">
<javac destdir="${build.dir}/classes"
  classpathref="${build.classpath}"
  debug="on">
  <src path="${src.dir}"/>
  <excludes name="**/.svn/**"/>
</javac>
</target>
```

Comment: i want to compile the package1 only, not all packages. but all packages are got compiled.  I looked at .svn, it does not have .java, but contains *.java.svn-base, *.java.svn-work.